# How to use multiple model boxes by calling different id functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use multiple model boxes by changing the class and id name of the model and its scripts but for some reason, instead opening respective model boxes for respective links, all id links are opening the one model box which is at the bottom of all.

So far my code:

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Text </a>
<a href="#" id="myBtntrain" > Train </a>

<div id="myModal" class="modalhospital">
  <div class="modal-contenthospital">
      <span class="closehospital"></span>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><strong>Is this Service for Self Or Someone Else ?</strong></p>
    <hr>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><a href="" class="modelonhover" >
        <strong style="float:left; padding-left:100px;color:#007AFF;">Self</strong></a><a href=""><strong style="float:right;padding-right:30px;color:#007AFF;">Someone Else</strong></a></p>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closehospital")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>



<div id="myModaltrain" class="modaltrain">
  <div class="modal-contenttrain">
      <span class="closetrain"></span>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><strong>Is this train for Self Or Someone Else ?</strong></p>
    <hr>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><a href="" class="modelonhover" >
        <strong style="float:left; padding-left:100px;color:#007AFF;">Self</strong></a><a href=""><strong style="float:right;padding-right:30px;color:#007AFF;">Someone Else</strong></a></p>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModaltrain");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtntrain");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closetrain")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm pretty new to this, just learning using w3 schools and other resources.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like i just have to name variables with individual names instead of same..

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Text </a>
<a href="#" id="myBtntrain" > Train </a>

<div id="myModal" class="modalhospital">
  <div class="modal-contenthospital">
      <span class="closehospital"></span>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><strong>Is this Service for Self Or Someone Else ?</strong></p>
    <hr>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><a href="" class="modelonhover" >
        <strong style="float:left; padding-left:100px;color:#007AFF;">Self</strong></a><a href=""><strong style="float:right;padding-right:30px;color:#007AFF;">Someone Else</strong></a></p>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closehospital")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>



<div id="myModaltrain" class="modaltrain">
  <div class="modal-contenttrain">
      <span class="closetrain"></span>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><strong>Is this train for Self Or Someone Else ?</strong></p>
    <hr>
    <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center;"><a href="" class="modelonhover" >
        <strong style="float:left; padding-left:100px;color:#007AFF;">Self</strong></a><a href=""><strong style="float:right;padding-right:30px;color:#007AFF;">Someone Else</strong></a></p>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var modaltrain = document.getElementById("myModaltrain");
var btntrain = document.getElementById("myBtntrain");
var spantrain = document.getElementsByClassName("closetrain")[0];
btntrain.onclick = function() {
  modaltrain.style.display = "block";
}
spantrain.onclick = function() {
  modaltrain.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modaltrain) {
    modaltrain.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

This solved my problem.. Anyways, thanks for your time guys..